# decrement value of a key list

Tags: python, key, decrement

i have a list of keys:values with integer values attached to particular keys...

these integer values represent the number of letters in a particular hand...

for example, here's a hand -

```
hand = {'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1} 
displayHand(hand) # Implemented for you
a q l l m u i
hand = updateHand(hand, 'quail') # You implement this function!
hand
{'l': 1, 'm': 1}
displayHand(hand)
l m
```

in this case - this call -

```
updateHand({'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 2, 'q': 1, 'u': 1}, quail)
```

should result in this outout -

```
{'a': 0, 'q': 0, 'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'l': 1}
```

notice how the letters in the word quail have all been decremented by one?

so how do I change the values of the keys by decrementing it by one if it is greater than zero?

here's the code that i have so far -

```
for c in word:

    if c in hand:
        x = int(hand.get(c))
        x -= 1

return hand
```

Comment: Please add the language as a tag.

Comment: And show what you've tried. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: This looks like simple substitution encryption, and Javascript. Sort've. Anyhow, in a functional sense you'd just take the input object and tokenize the input value to shift on that object by token, then move through the token list, decrementing it's associated value in the object. Then return. How to do that is language-dependent to a degree, though.

Comment: the language is in python....

Comment: Actually, it looks like he's implementing Scrabble. `hand` is the tiles he has, and `"quail"` is the word he just played.

Comment: here's what i have tried so far -  def updateHand(hand, word):for c in word:

        if c in hand:
            x = int(hand.get(c))
            x -= 1
    
    return hand

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: for c in word:

        if c in hand:
            x = int(hand.get(c))
            x -= 1
    
    return hand

Comment: how do i edit my questions?

Comment: I'll repeat: don't put code in comments, edit the question. Click on the "edit" link below the tags.

Comment: i edited it...added the code in the question

Comment: i added my code to it

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code:

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    for c in word:
        if c in hand:
            x = int(hand.get(c))
            x -= 1
    return hand
```

But this doesn't do anything to `hand`. Why not? Well, the line that tries to change stuff is the `x -= 1` line. But that just changes the value of `x`, which you just defined as `int(hand.get(c))`. In Python, this means that if `hand` has a value of `2` for `c`, you'll set `x = 2`. But it *doesn't* mean that changing `x` will change the value for `c` in `hand`. Instead, you need to do something a little different:

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    for c in word:
        if c in hand:
            hand[c] -= 1
    return hand
```

---

It doesn't matter in this particular situation, but this function actually modifies the input `hand` and then returns the same one. For example:

```
>>> hand = {'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 2, 'q': 1, 'u': 1}
>>> new_hand = updateHand(hand, 'quail')
>>> new_hand
{'l': 1, 'm': 1}
>>> hand
{'l': 1, 'm': 1}
```

Generally, you'd want to either have `updateHand` return a new dictionary and leave the old one alone, or have it not return anything and only modify the input argument. Since it looks like you were given the code

```
hand = updateHand(hand, 'quail')
```

you should do the first of those two. One way to accomplish this is to add `hand = hand.copy()` as the first line of `updateHand`; then it'll leave the old one alone.

---

Now, another thing is that your code is putting `0` values into the output if they used to be 1, but your assignment just doesn't include them at all. I'll leave you to figure out how exactly to handle this case, but as a hint for one way to do it: you can remove items from dictionaries through the statement `del hand[c]`.

---

Not recommending you do this, but as an aside for @Jared to show off Python a little bit: :)

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    return collections.Counter(hand) - collections.Counter(word)
```

(wrap return value in a call to `dict` to make it exactly the desired interface)

Comment: That makes Javascript look downright chatty. However, won't this reduce the value below 0? It may not be intended, but that was what I gathered.

Comment: Would be even cooler if there was something like `return hand.reduce(by)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I went through the trouble of doing it before we knew the language, so I might as well post it, but it's Javascript. Don't know how much of this may be Pythonizable<sup>©</sup>, but it gives the gist of my comment, and there's a working fiddle after to view.

Note, use a browser with an open Javascript console to see the output.

```
var hand = {a:1, q:1, l:2, m:1, u:1, i:1},
    quail = 'quail';

displayHand(hand);

hand = updateHand(hand, quail);

displayHand(hand);

function displayHand(obj) {
    var log = '',
        key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key]) {
            log += key;
        }
    }

    console.log(log.split('').join(' ') || 'Nothing');
}

function updateHand(obj, tokens) {
    var pos = 0,
        token;

    while (token = tokens[pos++]) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(token) && obj[token] > 0) {
            obj[token]--;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ybrn4/